# Clock: Unable to import kivy._clock on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5 using py2app

Tags: python, kivy, py2app

I'm encountering the following issue when attempting to repack a Python app on Mac using the py2app setuptools.

The app repacks just fine and runs flawlessly using Alias mode however when it's compiled for use on other machines it apparently cannot locate the ._clock module

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /Users/dimitargeorgiev/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-07-21_4.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.11.1
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "/Users/dimitargeorgiev/dist/AskSlava.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python36.zip/kivy/__init__.pyc"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at "/Users/dimitargeorgiev/dist/AskSlava.app/Contents/MacOS/python"
[ERROR  ] Clock: Unable to import kivy._clock. Have you perhaps forgotten to compile kivy? Kivy contains Cython code which needs to be compiled. A missing kivy._clock often indicates the Cython code has not been compiled. Please follow the installation instructions and make sure to compile Kivy
[WARNING] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/dimitargeorgiev/dist/AskSlava.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 411, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     _run()
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/dimitargeorgiev/dist/AskSlava.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 394, in _run
[WARNING] stderr:     exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
[WARNING] stderr:   File "/Users/dimitargeorgiev/dist/AskSlava.app/Contents/Resources/AskSlava.pyw", line 3, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:     from kivy.app import App
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/app.pyc", line 319, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/base.pyc", line 26, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/clock.pyc", line 363, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/_clock.pyc", line 14, in <module>
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/_clock.pyc", line 10, in __load
[WARNING] stderr:   File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
[WARNING] stderr:   File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 9, in init kivy._clock
[WARNING] stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.weakmethod'
```

Since it runs locally in alias mode I can assume the issue is not related to incorrect compilation of Kivy as the error fix suggestion implies.

I'm using
Python 3.6.0
Kivy 1.11.1
Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5
py2app

Some insight would be greatly appreciated

Regards,
Dimitar

Answer (score 0):

try using the option --packages (-p)

`python setup.py py2app --packages=PIL`

Comment: You could add more detail, to help OP as well as future readers